# Continuity of multiplication of maps in the strong topology

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that multiplication of maps is a continuous operation in the strong topology on the unit balls of L(X,U) and L(U,W),where X,U,W are all Banach spaces.
The strong topology is the weakest topology in which all functions L(X,U)→U of the form M→Mx are continuous for all x in X.
It seems that I need to discuss open sets in each topology,but I don't know how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by definition, for any topological space $Y$, a map $f \colon Y \to \def\so_{\mathrm{so}}L(X, W)_\so$ is continuous iff all maps $f_x := f(-)x \colon Y \to W$ are continuous. This is the so called universal property of the initial topology, the weakest topology such that the evaluation maps $\mathrm{ev}_x \colon L(X,W) \to W$, are continuous.

Now suppose $S_i \to S$ in $(B_{L(X,U)},\so)$ and $T_i \to T$ in $(B_{L(U,W)}, \so)$. We want to prove $S_i T_i \to ST$. For $x \in X$, we have 
\begin{align*}
  \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}
   \norm{STx - S_iT_ix} &= \norm{STx - S_iTx + S_iTx - S_iT_ix}\\
                        &\le \norm{(S-S_i)Tx} + \norm{S_i}\norm{T_ix - Tx}\\
                        &\le \norm{(S-S_i)Tx} + \norm{T_i x- Tx}
\end{align*} 
Now $(S-S_i)Tx \to 0$, as $S_i \to S$ and $T_i x - Tx \to 0$, as $T_i \to T$. Hence $S_iT_i x \to STx$.

Comment: Why the convergenve in strong topology is just the strong convergence? I just don't kown how to use the 'weakest'  here.

Comment: I now understand you,but I think use open sets rather than convergence will be better.Strong convergence can not pull back to convergence in strong topology.