# Continuity of multiplication of maps in the strong topology using open set

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Consider the question here: [Continuity of multiplication of maps in the strong topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468489/continuity-of-multiplication-of-maps-in-the-strong-topology)

I'm looking to an answer that does not assume that the product topology of the topologies induced by the strong topologies is metrizable.

I.e., suppose that $X,Y,Z$ are Banach spaces.

Let e.g., $B(X,Z)$ denote the set of linear bounded maps from $X$ to $Z$. Then the *strong topology* is the weakest topology such that $B(X,Z) \ni A \mapsto Ax \in Z$ is continuous for each $x\in X$. A basis elements $V$ of this topology is of the following form: Let $x_{1},\ldots,x_{n} \in X$, $z_{1},\ldots,z_{n} \in Z$ and $r_{1},\ldots,r_{n} \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$. Then

\begin{align}
V = \bigcap_{k=1}^{n}\{A\in B(X,Z) : Ax_{k} \in \{z\in Z : \| z - z_k \|_{Z} < r_k \} \}.
\end{align}

The goal is to prove that multiplication of maps is a continuous operation in the the product topology of the topologies induced on the unit balls by the strong topologies of $B(X,Y)$ and $B(Y,Z)$, respectively.

Comment: Just for context, why are you asking about the unit balls specifically? Does it fail on the whole spaces? Also, do you mean $Y,Z$ instead of $U,W$?

Comment: Fixed the second point. This is the way it is stated in "Functional Analysis" by Lax. However, the lecturer claimed that it is sufficient that $B(Y,Z)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. Here I show that the product map is continuous from the whole $B(X,Y)$ times the unitary ball of $B(Y,Z)$ to $B(X,Z)$.

Take $S\in B(X,Y)$, $T\in B(Y,Z)$. We know from your very well-written question (thank you for giving context to who is reading your post), that a basis of neighbourhoods for the operator $TS$ is given by all sets of the form $U_{\mathbf {x,r}}(TS)$,
$$ U_{\mathbf x,\mathbf r}(TS):=\{A\in B(X,Z)\,:\,\|A\mathbf x-TS\mathbf x\|_Z<\mathbf r\}, $$
where $\mathbf x, \mathbf r$ is a short notation for $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $r_1,\dots,r_n$, and $f(\mathbf x)<\mathbf r$ means $f(x_j)<r_j$ for all $1\leq j\leq n$ (forgive my aggressively aggressive notation; I realized too late that you can take an $r$ that is uniform in $j$ without loss of generality). For fixed $\mathbf{x,r}$, it is enough to show that there exist two neighbourhoods $V$, $W$ of $S$ and $T$ respectively such that $W\cdot V\subset U_\mathbf{x,r}(TS)$.

So, let $\mathbf y:=S\mathbf x$, $\mathbf z:=T\mathbf y$. Choose $V=U_{\mathbf x,\mathbf s}(S)$, and $W=U_{\mathbf y,\mathbf t}(T)$ with $\mathbf {s,t}$ to be chosen later (we also intersect $W$ with the unit ball in $B(Y,Z)$, which I don’t write down explicitly because I am out of letters). It is then straightforward (although a nightmare to write down) to show that $W\cdot V\subset U_\mathbf{x,r}(TS)$. In fact, taken two operators $C,D$ in $V,W$ respectively, by definition we have
$$ \|y_j-C x_j\|_Y=\|S x_j-C x_j\|_{Y}< s_i,  $$
$$ \|z_j-D y_j\|_Z=\|Ty_j-D y_j\|_Z<t_i, $$
and since $D$ has unit norm,
$$ \|D y_j-D(C x_j)\|_Z\leq\|y_j-C x_j\|_Y<s_i. $$
So, combining the above,
$$ \|(DC-TS) x_j\|_Z\leq\|D(C-S)x_j\|_Z+\|(D-T)S x_j\|_Z= $$
$$ =\|Dy_j-DCx_j\|_Z+\|Dy_j-z_j\|_Z< s_i+t_i. $$
So the above inclusion is proved by choosing $s_j=t_j=r_j/2$.

It seems the assumption of requiring $D$ to have bounded norm is crucial, so it seems the statement taking the full space $B(Y,Z)$ does not work. On the other hand, taking the whole $B(X,Y)$ indeed works, as your lecturer suggested.

Lot of fun XD

Comment: Perfect Saturday evening activity ;)